# Do any martial arts have mixed gender competitions?

Tags: gender

Do any martial arts have competitions where men fight women?

Answer (score 5):

It's common for light-contact karate divisions to not be divided by gender. Note the diminished importance of strength due to the lack of hard contact in this ruleset.

In American high-school wrestling, I hear girls often but not always compete with boys.

Male/female exhibition matches between men and women have occurred in boxing and kickboxing. In youth Muay Thai, girls often fight boys.

Comment: Interesting - I wonder if anyone has done any research on the outcomes of these competitions.   Does an exhibition match count as competition?  (I'm not sure I know what an "exhibition match" is really - not trying to be antaganistic)

Comment: An exhibition match means it doesn't go on your record, and it's not for competition but to demonstrate. In terms of research and outcomes, you're going to have to be more precise about what you mean.

Comment: I see, thanks.  In terms of research, I mean outcomes for men vs women in whatever the particular (martial arts based) competitive environment may be: much the same as boys vs girls are compared in academic environments  (girls win!)

Answer (score 2):

Aikido has mixed team competition.

Might be worth reviewing the [World Sport Aikido Federation](http://www.tomikiaikido.ie/WSAF-World-Sport-Aikido-Open-championships) event list, or the event list from the 2016 Tomiki Nationals. (I was there for part of those, but the only mixed gender I recall is team).  I can't find an event list for the nationals.

I would be surprised if taiji push hands tournaments didn't have some mixed.

Comment: Yes, although they are team events. I am unaware of any matches (takai as opposed to shihai) that pair male vs female. Informally, there are plenty of mixed bouts. I have very fond memories of being make to look like a kite by a certain female world champion.

Comment: Link to the [1st international WSAF competition](http://en.shodokanaikido.com/2017/1st-international-wsaf-competition/) which has a list of events. This is help in August 2017.

Answer (score 2):

There are occasionally Brazilian Jiu Jitsu tournaments with mixed gender divisions. They are extremely uncommon, and are only done in smaller tournaments because there would not be enough women to fill their own divisions.

A little anecdotal info: I've done two of these tournaments with mixed gender brackets. The women never did well. Even though they were in the same weight classes as their male opponents, I did not see a woman win a single match. That's not to say it isn't possible, it absolutely is! There are some amazing female BJJ practitioners. They just have a much tougher road ahead of them if they are to overcome their physical disadvantages and compete with men.